# Combinations of $n$ balls in $p$ distinguishable boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We put $n$ balls in $p$ distinguishable boxes. Assume that the balls are distinguishable. Find the number of possible combinations if

(a) Every box can receive only one ball at most.
(b) Every box can receive any number of balls.

Assume now that the balls are indistinguishable. 
Find the number of possible combinations if

(a) Every box can receive only one ball at most.
(b) Every box can receive any number of balls.

Deduce the number of solutions $k = (k_1, k_2, \dotsc, k_n)$ of the equation
$$\sum_{i=1}^n k_i = n$$
when the elements of $k$ are $0$ or $1$ and then when the elements of $k$ are integers.

Comment: It is considered impolite to simply copy-and-paste your homework question here without showing any effort of your own to solve it (or even format it nicely). See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Comment: For 1(a), there are $0$ ways if $n\gt p$. Now assume $p\ge n$. There are $\binom{p}{n}$ ways to choose the lucky boxes that will get a ball. For each such choice, there are $n!$ ways to assign the balls to the lucky boxes, for a total of $\binom{p}{n}n!$. This simplifies to $\frac{p!}{(p-n)!}$. For 1(b), each ball has $p$ choices about where to go, for a total of $p^n$. I urge you to (i) Show as much progress as possible and (ii) Ask a carefully chosen single question, or at most two closely related questions.

Comment: Aside from actually thinking about the problem _before_ posting, it is advisable to proofread it _after_ posting. It's hard for people to guess what"{unrecognized glyph}ni=1 ki = n" is supposed to mean. There is a little "edit" link on the lower left of the question that you can use to fix such things.

Comment: To make things a little easier, I put your unreadable equation into the format that is my best guess for what you meant. But you should check carefully that you did not write $n$ where you should have written $p$; I suspect you used the wrong variable in two places.

Comment: It looks like OP is gone, and the [same question was posted again](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148024/combination-of-p-books-and-n-balls).